# Spring Security 4.2.1.RELEASE + SSO CAS (jasig 4.0.3)

Tags: spring, spring-security

Estou usando o CAS (Jasig) com três aplicações, quando faço o logout de uma das aplicações eu finalizo a sessão do mesmo e do CAS, mas se eu acessar outra aplicação que já estava com uma sessão aberta via URL, a sessão fica viva. Como eu faço para matar todas as sessões ativas do meu conjunto de aplicações vinculadas ao CAS?

Exemplo:

- CAS
- APPLICATION A
- APPLICATION B
- APPLICATION C

Logout da aplicação A finaliza a mesma e o CAS, mas mantem as sessões vivas das aplicações B e C.

Tentei capturar o cookie criado pelo CAS para que eu possa desenvolver um "filter de logout" para verificar se o mesmo possui uma sessão ativa, mas não consegui capturar o mesmo.

Alguém já passou por uma situação parecida?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução para o problema, quando o CAS vai fazer o logout o mesmo executa uma determinada URL para informar para todos os sistemas vinculados que deve matar a sessão. Mas como estou utilizando o Spring Security o Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) estava bloqueando essa requisição. Após permitir que ele fizesse a mesma o problema foi resolvido.